# Where GKE logs store?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

as per documents GKE logs are stored in _Default container and it is free of cost if retention period(30 days) not changed. But I in Log Explorer I can able to fetch 1 year old logs. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

All information to answer your question can be found in Google Cloud docs - [Storing logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage).

You have 2 types of logs, `_Required` and `_Default`:

- **_Required**:

> This bucket holds Admin Activity audit logs, System Event audit logs, and Access Transparency logs, and retains them for 400 days. You aren't charged for the logs stored in _Required, and the retention period of the logs stored here cannot be modified. You cannot delete this bucket.

- **_Default**:

> This bucket holds all other ingested logs in a Google Cloud project except for the logs held in the `_Required` bucket. Log entries held in the `_Default` bucket are retained for `30 days`, unless you apply `custom retention` rules. You can't delete this bucket, but you can disable the `_Default` log sink that routes logs to this bucket.

In this documentation you also have little summary between `_Required` and `_Default` in `Logs retention` section.

| Logs bucket | Log types | Default retention | Custom retention |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| _Required | Admin Activity audit logs, System Event audit logs,and Access Transparency logs | 400 days | Not configurable |
| _Default | All other ingested logs | 30 days | 1 day to 3650 days |

With [Custom Retention](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#custom-retention) you can change duration of how long specific type of logs will be held depends on your needs.

Please keep in mind two important information in this Documentation.

- **Note:** Effective March 31, 2021, storage costs will apply to all chargeable logs retained longer than the default retention periods at the rate of $.01 per GiB per month (or fraction thereof). For details, see Logs storage pricing.
- There are currently no additional charges for extending logs data retention longer than the default retention periods.

### Conclusion

You have 2 types of logs bucket, `_Default` and `_Required`. While you are using default retention settings you don't have to pay additional charges.

**But I in Log Explorer I can able to fetch 1 year old logs**

In [Log Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-preview), you can check logs from last 400 days (default retention duration for `_Required` bucket) and you will be able to find information only about Admin Activity audit logs, System events, and access Transparency.

**Where GKE logs store**

This can be aswered in [Managing logs buckets](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/buckets) documentation.

> For each Cloud project, Logging automatically creates two logs buckets: _Required and _Default. All logs generated in the project are stored in the _Required and _Default logs buckets, which live in the project that the logs are generated in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In project reports huge Stack Driver Logging cost coming. In the Logs Storage I see 5TB of data in last month. Can you give me idea why the bill is coming if it is free. If it is because of volume, can I delete 3 months old data?

Comment: In the metrics browser I cheked global - Log Bytes ingested resources are:
bigquery_dataset, bigquery_dts_config, bigquery_project, bigquery_resource, build, cloud_composer_environment, cloud_dataproc_cluster, cloud_dataproc_job, cloud_function, cloud_run_revision, cloudsql_database, gce_instance, gce_instance_group, gce_target_pool, gce_bucket, gke_nodepool, http_load_balancer, k8s_cluster, k8s_container, k8s_node, k8s_pod, ml_job, uptime_url

Comment: Can you please let me what costing in Stack Driver Logging and how can I reduce it?

Comment: Asking about specific Stackdriver configuration is another question. According StackOverflow rules, new question should be posted as new question, not followed by comments. You can check [Pricing for Google Cloud's operations suite](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing) for additional information, but if this won't help you, you should create question with `stackdriver` and `google-cloud-platform` tags. Also some configuration of your `stackdriver` would help.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma does this answer your question about differences between keeping logs for 30 days and 1 year?